# Reserving a range of anonymous UIDs; /etc/subuid

Tags: docker, useradd, uid, usermod

I need a range of uids (say a few thousand) for a setuid-root tool to use. 
Is there a protocol to registering such a range or do I just pick a range and hope no other program will use those uids?

(I'd rather not create not clutter `/etc/passwd` with this.)

I came across `/etc/subuid` (among other places documented in https://www.mankier.com/8/usermod ) and it seems like that does something similar. What exactly is `/etc/subuid`, and can I use it to register a range for my setuid tool?

It appears this `/etc/subuid` stuff is used by docker for some kind of uid-mapping. If I create a new user for my app, reserve a subid range for it via `/etc/subuid` and then *not* use it with docker, would that be a good way to let the rest of the system know I've reserved a uid range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a hack, and then there is a way to do this *right*.

The hacky way is to raise `UID_MIN` and `GID_MIN` in `/etc/login.defs` so that your reserved UIDs fall between `SYS_UID_MAX` and `UID_MIN`, and GIDs (if any) between `SYS_GID_MAX` and `GID_MIN`. That way normal tools (`useradd`, `adduser`, `usermod`, etc.) do not use them for new user accounts, unless you force them to (by explicitly specifying the new UID and/or GID). You may need to remap any existing UIDs in this new gap range to the `UID_MIN`..`UID_MAX` range, and GIDs to the `GID_MIN`..`GID_MAX` range, so that tools treat them as normal user accounts.

The right way is to *additionally* configure [NSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) (and PAM, usually) to see these reserved users, so that tools do not get confused.

The simplest way to do this is to use `libnss-extrausers` NSS module, and `pam_extrausers` PAM module, so that you can put these special users in `/var/lib/extrausers/passwd` (and no-password entries in `/var/lib/extrausers/shadow`), plus optionally group information in `/var/lib/extrausers/groups`. These modules should be available in all common Linux distributions.

Note that if you do add these users to NSS/PAM, you may wish to extend `SYS_UID_MAX` and `SYS_GID_MAX` to cover these reserved users, just as a precaution: You see, I haven't checked if/which tools list only the `UID_MIN`..`UID_MAX` users, or just exclude the `SYS_UID_MIN`..`SYS_UID_MAX` users. I suspect there are a lot of programmers who mistakenly believe the two sets are complements of each other, so treating these reserved UIDs/GIDs as system accounts is probably the safest option.